# I have relationship many to many...whats right query to implement it knowing that my query contain if statement and paginate?

Tags: laravel-5

```
$guests = Guest::with('programs');
// dd($guests);
if ($request->session()->get('program_name') != -1)
    $guests->where('guest_fname', 'like' , '%' . $request->session()->get('search') . '%' )
        ->orderBy($request->session()->get('field'), $request->session()->get('sort'))
        ->whereHas('programs', function($q) use ($request) {
            $q->where('program_name', $request->session()->get('program_name'));
        })
        ->paginate(20);
```

whats right code to get data from DataBase?

Comment: Please explain the situation better, you can't just give us code and ask for a solution. What is it you are trying to do exactly? What is your output? Any errors?

Comment: Thank you I've got the correct query...I did it

Comment: @AlaaSalah either tidy this up and answer it yourself, for others' benefits; or delete the question then?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this has a canonical best answer. To be sure of finding it, we would need to know your table population.

Comment: yes I will share my answer , Joshua I have 2 tables many to many relation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $guests = Guest::with('programs')
        ->whereHas('programs', function($q) use ($request){
            if ($request->session()->get('program_name') != -1)
                $q->where('program_name', $request->session()->get('program_name'));
            $q->where('guest_fname', 'like', '%' . $request->session()->get('search') . '%');
        })
        ->orderBy($request->session()->get('field'), $request->session()->get('sort'))->paginate(5);
```